# Sort Tabs Alphabetically while Excluding Some in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following code to sort tabs alphabetically:

```
function sheetNames() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Store all the worksheets in this array
  var sheetNameArray = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());

  }


  sheetNameArray.sort();

 // Reorder the sheets.
  for( var j = 0; j < sheets.length; j++ ) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[j]));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(j + 1);

  }
}
```

I was just wondering if it's possible to exclude the 2x tabs 'Class List' and 'Template'? These tabs always needs to stay as 1 and 2 respectively and I'm not sure whether this requires a separate script to always 'lock' them in this position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to exclude these two sheets from the sorting and then sort the rest of the ones starting from the third position `j+3` until `length +3` but in this case you have to make sure you have already manually put them in the first and second position.

Another solution would be to add a code at the end of your current script, after the main sorting, to put the desired sheets in the first and second position respectively:

```
  ["Class List","Template"].forEach((name,i)=>{
              ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(name));
              ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1);                                                                       
              })
```

**Full code:**

```
function sheetNames() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Store all the worksheets in this array
  var sheetNameArray = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());

  }

  sheetNameArray.sort();

 // Reorder the sheets.
  for( var j = 0; j < sheets.length; j++ ) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[j]));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(j + 1);
  }
  
  ["Class List","Template"].forEach((name,i)=>{
              ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(name));
              ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1);                                                                       
        })
}
```